# query with both MATCH and CREATE

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 3 Nodes:

- `:User` which has a unique `id` property
- `:Palette` which has a unique `name` property
- `:Color` which has a unique `hex` property

When a user saves a pallete I would like to:

- create a new pallete if a palette with this name does not exist, and add a `:CREATED` relationship from the `:User` to the `:Palette`
- create a `:SAVED` relationship from the `:User` to the `:Palette` if one does not exist

Afterwards I would like to delete all `:INCLUDES` relationships that this `:Palette` has to `:Color` nodes inside the database (in order to create new ones afterwards).

This is my query (I replaced the variables with hardcoded strings so it's easier to execute):

```
MATCH (u:User)
    WHERE u.id = '4f3d1904'
MERGE (p:Palette {name: 'Test'})
    ON CREATE 
        SET p.name = "Test"
        MERGE (u)-[cr:CREATED]->(p)
MERGE (u)-[sa:SAVED]->(p)
MATCH (p:Palette {name: 'Test'})-[in:INCLUDES]->()
DELETE in
```

When running the query I get the following error:

> WITH is required between MERGE and MATCH (line 8, column 1 (offset: 181))
> "MATCH (p:Palette {name: 'Test'})-[in:INCLUDES]->()"
> ^

But if I add a `WITH` I get the following:

```
MATCH (u:User)
    WHERE u.id = '4f3d1904'
MERGE (p:Palette {name: 'Test'})
    ON CREATE 
        SET p.name = "Test"
        MERGE (u)-[cr:CREATED]->(p)
MERGE (u)-[sa:SAVED]->(p)
WITH
MATCH (p:Palette {name: 'Test'})-[in:INCLUDES]->()
DELETE in
```

> Invalid input ')': expected whitespace or a relationship pattern (line 9, column 32 (offset: 217))
> "MATCH (p:Palette {name: 'Test'})-[in:INCLUDES]->()"
> ^

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MERGE and MATCH stages (or MATCH and MATCH) require a WITH between them in order to use the result of the former in the latter.

In your case you can use the `p` that you already have like this:

```
...
WITH p 
MATCH (p)-[in:INCLUDES]->() 
DELETE in
```

So you won't need to find it again. without the WITH, it is like two different queries.